# (Angular-ui-router) Show loading animation during resolve process

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is a two part question:

1. I am using the resolve property inside $stateProvider.state() to grab certain server data before loading the controller. How would I go about getting a loading animation to show during this process?
2. I have child states that also utilise the resolve property. The problem is that ui-router seems to want to finalise **all** resolves before loading *any* controller. Is there any way I can get the parent controllers to load once their resolves have been resolved, without having to wait for all the child resolves? An answer to this will likely also solve the first problem.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @StefanHenze No, I just accepted this as a ui-router architectural flaw.

Comment: There's a discussion about this exact problem here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/456

Comment: @StefanHenze lol, no pun intended....

Answer (score 71):

EDIT: Here is an even easier solution, tested and working nicely:

In my main controller I simply have

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.resolve) {
        $scope.showSpinner();
    }
});
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.resolve) {
        $scope.hideSpinner();
    }
});
```

This shows the spinner whenever we are about to go to a state that has anything to resolve and hides it, when the state change is complete. You might want to add some check up the state hierarchy (i.e. also show the spinner if a parent state that is being loaded resolves something) but this solution works fine for me.

Here is my old suggestion for reference and as an alternative:

1. In your application controller, listen to the `stateChangeStart` event and check if you are about to switch to a state where you want to show a spinner during resolve (see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#wiki-events-1)

   ```
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
       if (toState.name == 'state.with.resolve') {
           $scope.showSpinner();  //this is a function you created to show the loading animation
       }
   })
   ```
2. When you controller finally gets called, you can hide the spinner

   ```
   .controller('StateWithResolveCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.hideSpinner();
   })
   ```

You also might want to check for any errors that may have occurred during resolve by listening to the `$stateChangeError` event and hiding the animation while you handle the error.

This is not totally clean as you distribute the logic for the spinner between controllers, but it's a way. Hope it helps.

Comment: `if (toState.resolve)` checks if the state config has a resolve dictionary. In my case, this is a good enough estimate that the state does async service calls. I assume that if there is a resolve block, it's service calls that get resolved. The code shows and hides the spinner only if service calls were made. As I described above, this code might need to be refined to also check parent states, depending on your use case.

Comment: in the 'old suggestion' you reference `$scope` inside a call on `$rootScope`. where does the `$scope` come from here?

Comment: @pdeva, the event handler was defined inside some controller; that's where also the `showSpinner` function was defined.

Comment: I couldn't use `toState.resolve` so I used `fromState.name !== toState.name`. Aside from that your answer is fantastic, well done!

Answer (score 22):

I developed the following solution which works perfectly for me.

**1. Add the following app.run**

```
app.run(function($rootScope){

    $rootScope
        .$on('$stateChangeStart', 
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
                $("#ui-view").html("");
                $(".page-loading").removeClass("hidden");
        });

    $rootScope
        .$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
                $(".page-loading").addClass("hidden");
        });

});
```

**2. Place the loading indicator just above the ui-view. Add id="ui-view" to ui-view div.**

```
<div class="page-loading">Loading...</div>
<div ui-view id="ui-view"></div>
```

**3. add the following to your css**

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

**NOTE:**

A. The above code will display loading indicator in two cases **1)** when the angular app is loaded first time **2)** when the view is changed.

B. If you don't want the indicator to be shown when the angular app loads first time (before any view is loaded), then add **hidden** class to  the loading div like below

```
<div class="page-loading hidden">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: That `run` code is soo not the Angular Way. Instead of manipulating the DOM there, set scope variables like `loadingVisible` and `viewVisible`, and then in the HTML, imperatively say when the elements are visible or hidden, like: `<div class="page-loading" ng-show="viewVisible">Loading...</div>`. For emptying the view it may require a custom directive though.

Comment: This is NOT recommended. Using jQuery inside angularcontext is nasty and is creating an unwanted dependency between your view and controller - not good practice!

Comment: I like this but ... Is it really correct in relation to the DOM?

Comment: The issue with doing this 'the angular way' like @MatthiasDailey suggests is that you'd need to duplicate the show/hide logic all over the place. The neat thing about this solution is that you can have a global method to show/hide the content or loaders. If you'd really want to do this the Angular way, then make a new directive that wraps ui-view

Comment: I think ng-class would be a better approach to this.

Answer (score 16):

I've found using the [angular-loading-bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/) worked really well for long resolves due to network access.

Answer (score 8):

How about adding content to the div that will be filled by ui-router once the properties have resolved?

In your `index.html`

```
<div ui-view class="container">
    Loading....
</div>
```

The user will now see "Loading..." while the properties are resolved. Once everything is ready the content will be replace by ui-router with your apps content.

Comment: This would work if your application can have a full app loading replacement, but falls short if you want to build 'loading...' hierarchically into your layout (eg. having part of your application show, with another part displaying loading...).

Comment: It's still a quick/dirty/easy way to get you moving on to more important things... like speeding up your resolves.

Comment: If you are loading multiple templates into that view, which ideally you would want to. The "loading...." message would appear only for the first time.

Comment: Is this possible in Ionic? I was not able to use this way in Ionic.

Answer (score 7):

I use an animated gif that I show only when `$http` has pending requests.

In my base page template, I have a navbar and navbar controller. The relevant part of the controller looks like this:

```
controllers.controller('NavbarCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.hasPendingRequests = function () {
            return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
        };
    }]);
```

The corresponding code in my html is:

```
<span class="navbar-spinner" ng-show="hasPendingRequests()">
    <img src="/static/img/spinner.gif">
</span>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: As you can see by my question, I don't have any access to controllers until all resolves have been finalised (which is the problem)!

Comment: You shouldn't use function for ng-show or ng-if, because they will be called in each digest loop. It will decrease performance.

Answer (score 4):

My idea is to walk the path on state graph between transitioning states on `$stateChangeStart` and collect all involved views. Then every `ui-view` directive watches if corresponding view is involved in transition and adds `'ui-resolving'` class on it's element.

The [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZwGnHfIkSRxOlci8DHm) demo introduces two root states: `first` and `second`, the latter has two substates `second.sub1` and `second.sub2`. The state `second.sub2` also targets `footer` view that belongs to its grandparent.

Answer (score 3):

**This is loader for globally when page navigate between any state (any page), put in app.js**

```
.run(
    ['$rootScope',
        function($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                $rootScope.preloader = true;
            })
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                $rootScope.preloader = false;
            })
        }
    ])
```

In html:

```
<div ng-show="preloader">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't be more obvious... maybe explain that how do you put something into the ui-view while the loading is in progress? Defining 2 variables is so trivial

Answer (score 3):

The use of `$stateChangeStart` and the like have since been deprecated and replaced with  [Transition Hooks](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks). So, for the answer by Stefan Henze, the updated version would be:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(transition) {
  if (transition.to().resolve) {
    $scope.showSpinner();
  }
});

$transitions.onSuccess({}, function(transition) {
  if (transition.to().resolve) {
    $scope.hideSpinner();
  }
});
```

You can use this in you parent controller. Remember to inject `$transitions` -

```
.controller('parentController',['$transitions',function($transitions){...}]);
```

Also, keep in mind that a `resolve` that is an empty object will still render `transition.to().resolve == true`, so don't leave an empty placeholder `resolve` in the state declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using a directive to match any loading activity, mainly to keep my codebase clean

```
angular.module('$utilityElements', [])
.directive('loader',['$timeout','$rootScope', function($timeout, $rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<div id="oneloader" class="hiddenload">loading...</div>',
      replace: true,
      compile: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function(){
          $rootScope
              .$on('$stateChangeStart',
                  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
                      $("#oneloader").removeClass("hiddenload");
              });

          $rootScope
              .$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
                  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
                      //add a little delay
                      $timeout(function(){
                        $("#oneloader").addClass("hiddenload");
                      },500)
              });
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

My Idea to use view while using resole in router it is working awesome. try this.

```
//edit index.html file 
<ion-nav-view>
    <div ng-show="loadder" class="loddingSvg">
        <div class="svgImage"></div>
    </div>
</ion-nav-view>

// css file

.loddingSvg {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.svgImage {
    background: url(../img/default.svg) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    background-size: 56px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

// edit app.js

 .run(function($ionicPush, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform) {




        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                $rootScope.loadder = true;
            });

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                $rootScope.loadder = false;
            });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using `ngRoute`, waiting on `resolve` before loading the next view, and using `angular-bootstrap-ui` for ui, you can do [the following](https://github.com/blaskovicz/MagicStick/commit/a226356fec66e8dd5d24af7df0401037106ff7d9):

```
app.config([
  "$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    return $routeProvider.when("/seasons/:seasonId", {
      templateUrl: "season-manage.html",
      controller: "SeasonManageController",
      resolve: {
        season: [
          "$route", "$q", "$http", "$modal", function($route, $q, $http, $modal) {
            var modal, promise, seasonId;
            modal = $modal.open({
              backdrop: "static",
              template: "<div>\n  <div class=\"modal-header\">\n    <h3 class=\"modal-title\">\n      Loading...\n    </h3>\n  </div>\n  <div class=\"modal-body\">\n    <progressbar\n      class=\"progress-striped active\"\n      value=\"'100'\">\n    </progressbar>\n  </div>\n</div>",
              keyboard: false,
              size: "lg"
            });
            promise = $q.defer();
            seasonId = $route.current.params.seasonId;
            $http.get("/api/match/seasons/" + seasonId).success(function(data) {
              modal.close();
              promise.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(data) {
              modal.close();
              promise.reject(data);
            });

            return promise.promise;
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
]);
```