# How can I bring up an "in progress" loading bar in between ui-router state transitions?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS application that uses ui-router.  There are times when the application waits while moving from one state to another and while the resolves are still in progress.

Does anyone have (or have they seen) any examples of how I can present an "in-progress" loading bar on the screen just during the time of the resolve from the one state to another?

Comment: I think promises can solve this. Maybe http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx could help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Angular-ui-router) Show loading animation during resolve process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961332/angular-ui-router-show-loading-animation-during-resolve-process)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the events emitted by `ui-router` (as well as the native `routeProvider`).

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tbO4MpvUuEIpoWhrGlzW?p=preview)

Something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    $rootScope.stateIsLoading = true;
})

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    $rootScope.stateIsLoading = false;
})
```

Then in HTML:

```
<section ui-view ng-hide="stateIsLoading"></section>
<div class="loader" ng-show="stateIsLoading"></div>
```

[docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

> You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data
>   that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller.
>
> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and
>   converted to a value **before the controller is instantiated and the
>   $stateChangeSuccess event is fired**.

Comment: State events have since been deprecated in ui-router 1.0. Check out [State Change Events Migration Example 2 of the migration guide](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events) for more up-to-date code which uses the Transition Hook API rather than events.

Comment: This is fantastic. Any suggestions on how to avoid $rootScope while doing this?