# in Angular. What's the best way to create an icon loading for pages?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am using with ui-route by the way

But I want to create something useful for all the site

That every time there is a request to the server

the icon will appear

Comment: [Learning how to google things is going to help you a lot if you want to be a good developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254584/how-can-i-bring-up-an-in-progress-loading-bar-in-between-ui-router-state-trans)

Comment: What about using angular-ui-bootstrap's [progressbar](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar) ? Not exactly what you're looking for, but if you can estimate a response time it's a nice addition

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a number of ways. Write an angular service that you call inside every request that sets a variable to true when a request goes out, and false when the response comes back. Then attach an ng-show to an element with the icon set to the variable.

Also you can look into the [$http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), which might prove useful as then you would not have to call the service for every request manually. Downside, it would trigger on every request which may not be the desired effect.