# Asynchronous communication cross pages

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular-ui-router, cross-domain, postmessage

I have a page `addin.html`. It can popup another page `editor` (which is not necessarily in the same domain) by

```
popup = window.open("https://localhost:3000/#/posts/editor/", "popup")
```

Then, the two pages have **each** one listener inside, and can send data to each other by

```
// listen:
function receiveMessage(event) {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.data);
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

// send:
function sendMessage() {
    popup.postMessage("data", popup.location.href);
}
```

`editor` is realised by `ui-router`. Initially, it resolves `init` before loading the page:

```
.state('editor', {
    controller: 'EditorCtrl',
    resolve: { init: [ ... ] },
    ...
};

app.controller('EditorCtrl', ['$scope', 'init', function ($scope, init) {
    ...
}]
```

What I want to implement now is, **when `addin.html` popups `editor`, it sends some data to `editor`, and `init` needs to resolve this data, before loading the page.** `editor` could hang before receiving the data from `addin.html`.

Does anyone know how to amend the receivers and senders (and something else) to accomplish this?

Comment: Couldn't you pass this initial data by URL parameters?

Comment: There may be lots of data, how could I embed them in `window.open`?

Comment: There aren't many choices. If data is too big, use server-side sessions to store and retrieve data. Or send data with POST.

Comment: @estus , I don't understand what you propose... unlike `editor`, `addin.html` does not have a server, and is not built with angularjs.

Comment: Why didn't you say anything about what is addin.html if it's important? The page doesn't need its own server to send something there. It just need *some* server. Why should it matter that it isn't built with Angular? It can use JS and thus do the things that I've suggested.

Comment: `addin.html` is important. As the name suggests, it has some limitations: it cannot have its own server, whereas it can have JS code. Could you make an answer with `server-side sessions` and `POST`?

Comment: This will be a duplicate of existing questions, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit . As any other popular topic, it was already thoroughly discussed on SO. I can't say anything on server-side sessions, because it solely depends on your server side. Btw, you will need some server-side magic to make POST variables available in Angular app, too.

Comment: you already pass "popup", which isn't that useful. pass your data instead and it's available as `window.name` in the popup. since you assign a var _popup_, you don't even need to pass that name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a custom promise and resolve it whenever you want as the following code

```
.state('editor', {
  controller: 'EditorCtrl',
  resolve:{
    init: function($q){
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
              deferred.resolve(event.data);
         }, false);
         return deferred.promise;
     }
  }
});
```

The controller waits for above item to be completely resolved before instantiation.

Comment: thank you... I have not tested it... so visually, what will users see before resolving? A blank page?

Comment: Hi, yes the ui-view will be empty before resolving http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961332/angular-ui-router-show-loading-animation-during-resolve-process