# Pre-resolve behaviour to render skeletons?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In UI-Router you have the ability to resolve data before the state change. This is obviously kind of blocking the change, until the resolve has finished.

**My question**

Is there a way to fill the target view with a skeleton template, to indicate that the state change is going on?

Something like:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state("management", {
    url: "/management",
    views: {
      "management-view": {
        component: "njCloudManagement"
      }
    },
    preview: {    // <-- something like this?
      "management-view": {
        template: "skeleton.html"    
      }
    }
    params: {
      id: {
        type: "string",
        value: ""
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      mightyResolve: () => {}
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a intermediate skeleton controller and view, then display the view.

Then load your resolve data.

Finally move to your appropriate view with data.

Answer (score 0):

In your main controller, listen to state changing events and show spinner based on those events. This was really well demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21369373/3132275) answer.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.resolve) {
        $scope.showSpinner();
    }
});
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.resolve) {
        $scope.hideSpinner();
    }
});
$scope.hideSpinner = function(){
  // your spinner showing code here
}
```